# Как преобразовать список без .split?

Tags: python-3.x, list, строки

Как сделать из такого списка ['str1 str2'] такой ['str1', 'str2'] не используя метод .split()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перебирая исходную строку, добавлять каждый символ кроме пробела в новую строку. Если встречается пробел - добавлять новую строку элементом списка и обнулять её.

```
a = ["azz bsdf cd"]

arr = []
el = ''
for i in a[0]:
    if i == " ":
        arr.append(el)
        el = ''
        continue
    el += i
arr.append(el)
print(arr)
# ['azz', 'bsdf', 'cd']
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Если нельзя `split()` то можно попробовать рекурсивную функцию:

```
a = ["azz bsdf cd"]

def f(a):
    i = a.find(' ')
    return [a] if i==-1 else [a[:i]] + f(a[i+1:])

f(a[0])
```

вывод:

```
['azz', 'bsdf', 'cd']
```